# Child theme - Javascript not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, themes

I am trying to load javascript files for my plugin and it worked until I changed my theme to a child theme and then updated the original theme... any ideas why the javascript has stopped firing? All I have included in the child theme folder is a style.css file.

The javascript line that is not firing apparently is:

```
wp_enqueue_script('watchlist',THT_WATCHLIST_DIR.'assets/js/watchlist.js',array('jquery','jquery-ui-1','jquery-ui-tabs1','jquery-ui-datepicker1','jquery-ui-dialog1','jquery-ui-button1',), '1.0.0', 1 );
```

Thanks!

```
----main plugin file-----
function tht_add_javascript_files() {

if (!is_admin()) {

    wp_enqueue_style('watchlist-css',THT_WATCHLIST_DIR.'assets/css/watchlist.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker1', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js', array('jquery-ui-core'), '1.10.3', 1 );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-position', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.position.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.10.3', 1 );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog1', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.min.js', array('jquery','jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-position','jquery-ui-button1'), '1.10.3', 1 );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-button1', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.button.min.js', array('jquery','jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-position'), '1.10.3', 1 );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs1', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js', array('jquery-ui-widget'), '1.10.3', 1 );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-menu', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.menu.min.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-position' ), '1.10.3', 1 );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-1', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js', array('jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-widget'), '1.10.3', 1 );

    wp_enqueue_script('watchlist',THT_WATCHLIST_DIR.'assets/js/watchlist.js',array('jquery','jquery-ui-1','jquery-ui-tabs1','jquery-ui-datepicker1','jquery-ui-dialog1','jquery-ui-button1',), '1.0.0', 1 );
}

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tht_add_javascript_files');
```

Comment: What is the value of `THT_WATCHLIST_DIR`

Comment: @elzi thanks... /wp-content/plugins/tht-watchlist/ (all looks fine to me... ie changing to child theme won't have changed that file destination I don't believe...)

Comment: If you're trying to access a plugin directory, you should define (in the plugin) something like `define( 'THT_WATCHLIST_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );` then use that

Comment: DEFINE("THT_WATCHLIST_DIR", '/'.PLUGINDIR .'/'.dirname(plugin_basename (__FILE__)).'/'); --- i've put this in already... and the file has fired before, just not since the child theme unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id say offhand somewhere in the parent theme will be

```
define(THT_WATCHLIST_DIR, get_stylesheet_directory() );
```

it needs to be:

```
define(THT_WATCHLIST_DIR, get_template_directory() );
```

so you can use child themes. Either change in the theme and let the developer know about this or copy your js folder over to the child theme!

**update**

I am getting a 404 error for all your js files and pages as well. There may be a few things that are causing this. Dealing with your 404 issues first

1. flush your permalinks, copy your .htaccess file and save somewhere
   replace the contents of  your .htaccess file with this:

   ```
   # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   # END WordPress
   ```
2. undo the theme change you made.
3. check your wp-options db table - what value for home_url / site_url?
4. apache mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

For your files
 1. check the folder js actually exists in your theme
 2. check folder permissions for js file ->should be 755 for the directories in your theme.
 3. try the 2014 theme -> check your browser console (right click on a page element->inspect element and click on console in the pop up window) is there any errors? If not check your theme urls to js folder again, if there is errors, contact your hosting or check your apache settings again.

Comment: Other way around isn't it? [In the event a child theme is being used, that is the directory that will be returned, not the parent theme directory (use get_template_directory() instead if you want the parent directory)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)

Comment: Oh - nvm, I see. Defined in parent theme.

Comment: Duplicating the js file from the parent to the child theme folder ie fruitful/js doesn't do anything unfortuantely :-(

Comment: Changed the child theme back to the original parent... file still not firing, so actually it's something to do with the theme update which I applied I think. Could it be a js conflict?

Comment: whats the url of the site and ill have a look?

Comment: oncapitalpartners dot com David

Comment: do you have a caching plugin enabled? can you disable it?

Comment: and thanks ;-)... I'm stumped. just about to try an: echo file_exists("test.txt"); tho... see if that throws anything.

Comment: caching plugin...  yes will disable... W3 Total Cache... wasn't enabled actually...

Comment: cool btw reset your permalinks as well (settings ->permalinks and save to postname if thats what you use?)

Comment: Just checked... permalinks already saved to postname... could you see a problem with them your side?

Comment: yes you need to flush them by saving again. Basically every page on your site (including landing page) is sending me to 404 page. ill update my answer with a few things to try, am i right in saying you have changed hosts recently?

Comment: Actually I've got an IP block for 99% of countries whilst I'm developping... had many many hackers trying to muck things up so I did that. Which country are you in, I'll enable you... it's not a real 404 :-) and I'm not really changing hosts...

Comment: Oh man you're up as late as me!!! ok you should be good to go now... really appreciate the help.

Comment: true but finishing now. You still have a lot of 404's if you check your console (right click in chrome and inspect element and then console) you will see all the js errors and files not found! ill have another tomorrow if you dont get it sorted but if all you did was install the child theme and make a change update your q with the change as well.